# Whats the point of SDI being "source/destination" identifier if 429 busses are only allowed to have 1 transmitter?

Tags: bus, aerospace

Every reference I've looked at for Arinc429 specification has something like this:

[image]

Okay, pretty simple. There is only one transmitter and up to 20 receivers.

However, the name of the SDI (source/destination identifier) field is confusing me.

It implies that there can be multiple transmitters by allowing you to define "where" the message has come from being sent to a receiver.

Is that simply useful for debugging purposes? It might make sense if there some sort of data recorder listening to all the arinc buses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image from [ARINC-429 TUTORIAL & REFERENCE](https://www.ueidaq.com/arinc-429-tutorial-reference-guide) indicates that the SDI field is used to indicate which reciever is to process the message.

EDIT: A source does not necessarily mean a transmitter.

Several hardware or software sources can/may share the same transmitter. Each destination may procss messages from one or more of these sources as indicated in the field.

[image]

Comment: You said "each destination may process messages from one or more sources". What other sources? There's only one, the transmitter, which was the whole point of the question.

Comment: In general there is no reason that several sources cannot share the same transmitter. The tutorial may indicate whether the Arinc-429 does this or not. I haven't done through the tutorial or the specification. If there must be one transmitter per source, then the field can only be used to indicate destination.@SimonFitch

Comment: Furthermore a single reciever could also service several destinations. @SimonFitch